# Enum with Enum elements in Python3

Tags: python-3.x, list, enums

I'm setting an enumeration "A" of possible commands in my Python code.
I would also create another enumeration "B" listing some specific commands "A".

Thus I tried :

```
class all_commands(IntEnum):
    SET_ELEMENT_A = 0x00000001
    GET_ELEMENT_A = 0x00000007
    GET_ELEMENT_B = 0x0000000E
    SET_ELEMENT_C = 0x00000010
    GET_ELEMENT_C = 0x00000011
    GET_ELEMENT_D = 0x00000015

class getter_commands(IntEnum):
    all_commands.GET_ELEMENT_A
    all_commands.GET_ELEMENT_B
    all_commands.GET_ELEMENT_C
    all_commands.GET_ELEMENT_D
```

This seems correct to me, however when I try

```
all_commands.GET_ELEMENT_A in getter_commands
```

I get a `False` result value.

Is that a normal behaviour ? Or is my code wrong ?

I tried using a list, which works with `all_commands.GET_ELEMENT_A` but I think an `Enum` type would be better

```
getter_commands = [all_commands.GET_ELEMENT_A,
                all_commands.GET_ELEMENT_B,
                all_commands.GET_ELEMENT_C,
                all_commands.GET_ELEMENT_D]
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: `all_commands.GET_ELEMENT_A` accesses attribute, it doesn't save it to `getter_commands` class fields

Comment: So there is no way to use a second `Enum` referencing the first, right ?

Comment: you can do `GET_ELEMENT_A = all_commands.GET_ELEMENT_A` if you want to have a member `GET_ELEMENT_A` in `getter_commands` enum

Answer (score 0):

`Enum` is not the solution to you problem.  What you need is something like an `EnumSet` which would allow iteration, containment checks, and attribute access.  So something that is created like:

```
getter_commands =  EnumSet(
    all_commands.GET_ELEMENT_A,
    all_commands.GET_ELEMENT_B,
    all_commands.GET_ELEMENT_C,
    all_commands.GET_ELEMENT_D,
    )
```

and with behavior:

```
>>> list(getter_commands)
[all_commands.GET_ELEMENT_A, all_commands.GET_ELEMENT_B, all_commands.GET_ELEMENT_C, all_commands.GET_ELEMENT_D]

>>> getter_commands.GET_ELEMENT_C
<all_commands.GET_ELEMENT_C: 16>

>>> all_commands.GET_ELEMENT_D in getter_commands
True

>> all_commands.SET_ELEMENT_A in getter_commands
False
```

---

Such an object could look like:

```
class EnumSet:

    def __init__(self, *enum_members):
        self.__dict__.update({m._name: m for m in enum_members})

    __iter__ = self.__dict__.values
```

Comment: Tank you, that should do the job !

Comment: @Ulysse:  You're welcome!  When you find answers helpful remember to vote them up (click on the up arrow by the answer title); also, you should select the answer that was the most helpful, or that you like the most, and click on the check mark by it.  This helps other folks looking for an answer to the same problem.